# Render JSON with collapsibility

Tags: gratis, open-source, library, javascript, json

I'm looking for an FOSS Javascript library for rendering JSON with the ability to collapse nested objects.

This will be for rendering in the DOM so browser plugins won't do. Much like http://json.parser.online.fr/beta/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`pretty-json`](https://github.com/warfares/pretty-json) does exactly that and is under the following [licence](https://github.com/warfares/pretty-json/blob/master/build/license.txt):

> I dont think too  much about licence
>
> just feel free to do anything you want... :-)

A demo can be seen [here](http://warfares.github.io/pretty-json/).

Comment: At a quick look I would say this is a better solution for any complicated cases; very simple cases the one I posted may be better due to its simplicity - though the javascript processing cost is now so low compared to most systems that is a **very** minimal concern really.

Answer (score 4):

Just whipped a quick dirty up: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/z9Rkr/)

css:

```
ul {
    margin-left: 1em;
}

.json-key {
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ui-icon {
    float:left;
    margin-right:3px;
}

.childless {
    margin-left:18px;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
    function visitObj($container, obj) {
        var $ul = $('<ul>');

        for (var prop in obj) {

            var $li = $('<li>');
            if (typeof obj[prop] === "object") {
                $li.append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-plus"></span><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minus"></span><span class="json-key">' + prop + ': </span>');
                 visitObj($li, obj[prop]);
            } else {
                $li.append('<span class="json-key childless">' + prop + ': </span><span class="json-value">'+obj[prop]+'</span>');                   
            }
            $ul.append($li);
        }
        $container.append($ul);
    }

    visitObj($('#json-viewer'), {
       "Attempted":"EditUser",
       "Exception":{
          "Message":"Something",
          "TargetSite":"somewhere",
          "Inner Exception":{
             "Message":"Something else",
             "TargetSite":"somewhere.core",
                 "Inner Exception":{
                "Message":"Another message",
                "TargetSite":"something.core.subr",
                "Inner Exception":{
                   "Message":"Object reference not set to an instance of an object.",
                   "TargetSite":"System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Update(Int32, System.String, System.String)",
                   "StackTrace":[
                      "at Application.Controllers.AdminController.Update(Int32 id, String email, String password) in c:\\Docs\\Apps\\Main\\MyBranch\\Source\\Application\\Application\\Controllers\\AdminController.cs:line 123"
                   ],
                   "Inner Exception":{

                   }
                }
             }
          }
       },
       "details":{
          "userEmail":"test@email.com",
          "userId":"25",
          "userRole":"User"
       }
    });
$(".ui-icon-plus").hide();
$("#json-viewer li").each( function () {
    $(this).click(function (event) {
        $(this).children("ul").toggle();
        $(this).children(".ui-icon").toggle();
        event.stopPropagation();
    });
});
```

html:

```
<div id="json-viewer"></div>
```

Requires the jQuery UI library for the plus/minus sign to display so must have something like this:

This is significantly based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13341373/render-arbitrary-json-in-html) - I just added the section hiding/showing basically.